# Win32 API: Child windows with different images

Tags: winapi, assembly, masm32

I was given a assignment at the university: to write a game in `MASM`. I chose a game the type of "three in a row". Objects in the game are some sweets: ice cream, lollipop, etc. But I have a problem. I don't know how to make child windows with different images. I've tried, but nothing is working. Maybe someone knows how to implement this? Any help is appreciated. Even in `C/C++`. I would be glad if someone just explain to me in words how to do it. The main thing for me is to understand the concept.

I have

[image]

But I need this

[image]

Comment: Start by learning how to do this in C++

Comment: @DavidHeffernan for me it doesn't matter in what programming language to write. As I already mentioned, I just don't know how to implement it.

Comment: @Gerardo I already showed the code here. And it didn't bring me any good. Idea, concept how to do it - that's what important.

Comment: If you don't know how to paint in a Windows program, and you want us to teach you, then the question is too broad. Why don't you read a good book, or a good online tutorial?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what you see in the first picture - I did it. I know something, but of course not everything. I read some books and surfed the Internet, but nothing like that. I've tried some things, but they didn't work.

Comment: I can't see a picture, just a link to some off site resource. We don't really like that here. And what are we to do with those images? Can't we see your code. Show a [mcve] please. It feels like you want somebody to do your homework for you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have the main window and class of child windows called "SweetsWindow". Of course, I have functions `RegisterClassSweetsWindow` and `CreateSweetsWindow`. And when I call `CreateSweetsWindow` in `WM_CREATE` of the main window I have one image for every child window. And I want them to have different images.

Comment: I guess you need to fix your code. We can't see it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm sorry, I don't have enough reputation to post pictures. And I don't want somebody to do my homework for me. I just need some help, because I'm stuck. And I'll try to post my code.

Comment: You need to work hard on your question asking. It needs to be far more focused. You need to show a [mcve]

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and now can you give me some advice?

Comment: Not me, asm Win32 programming is not my thing. But the question is better now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you have JUST ONE IMAGE, because hBit IS A GLOBAL VARIABLE, hBit is overwritten in all calls to CreateSweetsWindow, in fact: it retains last image loaded.

I suggest you add hBit to SweetsWindowStruct struct:

```
SweetsWindowStruct struct
    stype   SWEETSTYPE     ?
    sweetsID DWORD         ?
    hBit HBITMAP           ?
SweetsWindowStruct ends
```

And remove global hBit (line 44 in your sweets.asm file), you must change WM_PAINT code like this:

```
 .elseif [iMsg] == WM_PAINT

    invoke BeginPaint, [hwnd], addr ps
    mov [hdc], eax

    invoke CreateCompatibleDC, hdc
    mov [hMemDC], eax

    SweetsWindowStruct *sws;// sorry show you in c++
    sws = (SweetsWindowStruct*)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA);
    HBITMAP hBit = sws->hBit;

    invoke SelectObject, hMemDC, [hBit]
    mov [oldDC], eax
```

Other issue: i think you have a error, where you say:

```
invoke SetWindowLong, [hwnd], 0, addr [sws]
```

it must be:

```
invoke SetWindowLong, [hwnd], GWL_USERDATA, addr [sws]
```

Please check that